# How do I get an entity's ID in an NHibernate listener before it's saved to the database?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, events, fluent-nhibernate, identity

We have a new requirement that every entity must have a user-assignable ID:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int ServerId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

The `ServerId` is an auto-generated ID using HiLo and the `UserId` is the user-specified ID. However, if the user does NOT set a `UserId`, it should default to whatever `ServerId` is. So I created a listener like this:

```
public class CustomEventListener : IPreInsertEventListener
{
    public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent @event)
    {
        var entity = @event.Entity as Entity;

        if (entity.UserId == 0)
        {
            entity.UserId = entity.ServerId;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, at this pre-insert stage, the `ServerId` is always 0, so the `UserId` is always 0. Does anyone know how I can get the generated `ServerId` **before** it's saved to the database but **after** the `ServerId` is populated by NHibernate?

P.S. I'm also assuming that this is impossible with the `Identity` generator because it saves to the database and then gets the ID that the DB used. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: In my case it works, calling Save generates the Id, calling Flush inserts it into the database. Maybe you will have to listen to the Post Insert event instead.

Comment: No dice. Post Insert occurs after the flush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to Ayende's blog post here:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/29/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-amp-ipreinserteventlistener.aspx

Turns out you have to not only change it in the entity, but also the entity state:

```
public class CustomEventListener : IPreInsertEventListener
{
    public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent @event)
    {
        var entity = @event.Entity as Entity;

        if (entity.UserId == 0)
        {
            entity.UserId = entity.ServerId;
            Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "UserId", entity.UserId);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void Set(IEntityPersister persister, object[] state, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        var index = Array.IndexOf(persister.PropertyNames, propertyName);
        if (index == -1)
            return;
        state[index] = value;
    }
}
```